# Declare python module in yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file which has some fields with values that are understandable in python, but they get parsed as string values, not that python type I meant. This is my sample:

```
verbose:
   level: logging.DEBUG
```

and obviously when I load it, the value is string type

```
config = yaml.load(args.config.read(), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
```

I have no idea how to get exactly `logging.DEBUG` object, not its string.

Note that I don't look for configuring logging to get logger thing. This logging is just a sample of python module.

Comment: Do you want to keep the yaml structure as is, or are you ok with e.g. using some custom tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no out of the box way for that. The simplest and safest way seems to be processing the values manually, e.g:

```
import logging

class KnownModules:
    logging = logging
    ...


def parse_value(s):
    v = KnownModules
    for p in s.split('.'):
        v = getattr(v, p)  # remember to handle AttributeError
    return v
```

However, if you're ok with slightly changing your YAML structure, PyYAML supports some [custom YAML tags](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#yaml-tags-and-python-types). For example:

```
verbose:
    level: !!python/name:logging.DEBUG
```

will make `config['verbose']['level']` equal to `logging.DEBUG` (i.e. `10`).

Considering that you're (correctly) using `SafeLoader`, you may need to combine those methods by defining your own tag.

Comment: Those tags are probably (hopefully?) not known when using SafeLoader.

Comment: @AKX that's true, though it's still possible to define a custom tag.

Answer (score 3):

The YAML loader has no knowledge of what `logging.DEBUG` might mean except a string `"logging.DEBUG"` (unless it's tagged with a YAML tag).

For string values that need to be interpreted as e.g. references to module attributes, you will need to parse them after-the-fact, e.g.

```
def parse_logging_level(level_string: str):
    module, _, value = level_string.partition(".")
    assert module == "logging"
    return logging._nameToLevel[value]

# ...

yaml_data["verbose"]["level"] = parse_logging_level(yaml_data["verbose"]["level"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Please see AKX answer. I was not aware of `logging._nameToLevel` which does not require defining your own enum and is definitely better than using `evel`. But, I decided to not delete this answer as I think the current preferred design (as of python 3.4) which uses enums is worth mentioning (it would probably be used in the logging module if it was available back then).

---

If you are **absolutely sure** that the values provided in the config are legitimate ones, you can use `eval` like this:

```
import logging
levelStr = 'logging.DEBUG'
level = eval(levelStr)
```

But as said in the comments, if you are not sure about the values present in the config file, using `eval` could be disasterous (see the example provided by AKX in the comments).

A better design is to define an enum for this purpose. Unfortunately the logging module does not provide the levels as enum (they are just constants defined in the module), thus you should define your own.

```
from enum import Enum
class LogLevel(Enum):
    CRITICAL = 50
    FATAL = 50
    ERROR = 40
    WARNING = 30
    WARN = 30
    INFO = 20
    DEBUG = 10
    NOTSET = 0
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
levelStr = 'DEBUG'
levelInt = LogLevel[levelStr].value # Comparable with logging.DEBUG which is also an integer
```

But to use this you have to change your yml file a bit and replace `logging.DEBUG` with `DEBUG`.

Comment: Never, ever use `eval` on user input. Consider an evil value for `levelStr` such as `'__import__("os").system("rm -rf $HOME")'`...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please see the completed answer which I also emphasized on this point. @AKX